# Bitrix вывод в сайдбаре

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Как отредактировать вывод в сайдбаре https://ldkc.ru/stomatologiya/  Нужно чтобы выводились подразделы, по структуре находящиеся в данном разделе. Где лежит файл отвечающий за этот вывод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае надо для блога подразделы сделать? Тогда использовать механику формирования разделов и вывода новостей через компонент bitrix.blog , после установки которого в urlrewrite появится запись вида

```
array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/blog/ct/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:blog',
    'PATH' => '/blog/ct/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
```

Если уже есть готовые статические страницы, воспользуйтесь urlrewrite (обратите внимание на RULE)

```
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9а-яёА-ЯЁ_(\\%2F)\\-]+)$#u',
    'RULE' => 'query=$1&$3',
    'PATH' => '/blog/service/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
```

P.S  Ссылки - неточные, напишИте под свой случай)
Напишите мне в комментариях, в каком направлении ВАМ удобно продолжить работу, ЧЕМ ВАМ рассказать? Я пока сейчас предложил статические страницы воткнуть. А Вам за какое время и каким образом хотелось-бы, чтобы это работало? Напишите в комментах, что ТАК, а что НЕ ТАК